# I deleted Windows\Installer folder, is there a chance to repair?

Tags: windows-7, installer, windows-installer

I accidentally deleted the `Windows\Installer` folder in Windows 7. Is there a way to repair this, because I can't install new Microsoft software anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows install cd and selecting the repair option?

Answer (score 5):

Try recovering the files using a Shadow Copy (Previous Versions).  If your edition of Windows doesn't expose the Previous Versions tab, use the free [ShadowExplorer](http://shadowexplorer.com/) to do it.

If that doesn't work, recover from backup.

If you don't have a backup, you're in big trouble.

The only real options you have at that point are reinstalling Windows (and all of your applications that use Windows Installer) or, maybe, trying to use the `msizap.exe` command line tool to reset all the Installer's registry information.

Comment: msizap *! ALLPRODUCTS worked for me - but as a last ditch effort - not recommended!  Everything has to be reinstalled now.

Answer (score 2):

Open an elevated command prompt and type:

```
sfc /scannow
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Answer (score 2):

You can't reinstall it, because actually version 5.0 is not redistributable.

The simplest solution is to copy the folder from an other Win7 computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using System restore, or even just restore from the recycle bin?